# How to change search result url structure in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a site where it results all the paragraphs with the keyword used to search and the language selected. But the url it returns is not what I want it to look like.

The current url is like the one given below,

```
petergraae.com/petergraae.com/search_result/?language=10&search_word=banana+(adj.)
```

Where language=10 is for English. And I want the url like the one given below,

```
petergraae.com/petergraae.com/English/banana
```

I have heard that it can be done through .htaccess file but need proper guidance.

Here is the screenshot of the search result page:

[image: search result]

Comment: Why on earth would you want to repeat your domain name? Surely you would prefer `petergraae.com/English/banana` ?

Comment: @thickguru it is already that way, Because my wordpress is in a sub directory.

Answer (score 0):

Although this can be achieved by modifying your .htaccess file, the correct way of doing this on wordpress is by using the built in [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). More specifically you would use the `add_rewrite_rule()` [function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

Comment: Can you please explain it in brief please?